# Openrowset doesn't execute in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, import, ssms, openrowset

I am trying to take data from an Excel sheet and store it into SQL Server 2019 through the `Openrowset` statement. First I asked to enable 'ad hoc distributed queries' and 'show Advanced Options', which I did, but still alleged to execute it gets stuck and not is not providing the desired result. I'm doing this on my local computer.

Example query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                 'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Users\Public\Documents\Prueba.xlsx',
                 'Select * from [Hoja1$]')
```

AND it is a small Excel file, just a test, 10 rows, no more, I'm doing this on my local computer, I've done it before in my job computer and it works, but not here.

Comment: Do you get some kind of an error message? Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77013998/edit) your question to include the full and complete error message - as text, not screen shot(s).

Comment: These queries are executed by SQL Server, and the SQL Server service is running in the context of a particular user (see Services.msc, for example, to see which user that is). Does that service user have read/write access granted to it in the filesystem permissions for the `C:\Users\Public\Documents` folder? Is the Excel file closed? (Office applications hold non-shareable locks on files they have open.)

Comment: Also, `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` (Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010) is quite old, do you have it installed? Are you not using a more current version, like `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0` (Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016)?

Comment: Note that using the ACE OLE provider as a linked server is not a supported scenario (because it's designed for GUI applications) so you won't get any help from Microsoft. It sort-of works, but don't be surprised if you have problems. Instead use a proper import tool such as SSIS.